# When opening one dynamic created button all buttons are opening

Tags: c#, wpf

I am testing a small app where main window has a text box for entry, user clicks add (List Add in code) and it updates a simple list. In addition to the list update a dynamic button will be created in a wrap panel. The idea is the user then can click what ever entry they need to update and it load the second window with that entry correlated to an index in the list.

I have code that works for the most part but am blanking on what I believe is something trivial. If there is 3 buttons created and I go to click button 3 it will pop up all entries. So three windows with their assigned index. I just need the one window to show for the button that was clicked. I have played around and this particular issue is escaping me.

I have searched for a similar answer but came up short over the past few days.

MainWindow:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace TestApp
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        List<string> listA = new List<string>();

        private int x = 1;       
        private int t = 1;

        private void addBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {            
            listA.Add(listBx.Text);

            Button btns = new Button();
            btns.Width = 70;
            btns.Height = 30;
            btns.Content = "Button " + x;
            btns.Name = "Btn" + t;
            btns.Click += (s, t) =>
            {
                for (int index = 0; index < listA.Count; index++)
                {                    
                    EditWindow win = new EditWindow();
                    win.updateBx.Text = listA[index];
                    win.Show();                    
                }
            };
            btnPanel.Children.Add(btns);
            x++;
            t++;
        }

    }
}
```

Second window (no code here yet, update btn will rewrite list index it correlates with:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace TestApp
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for EditWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class EditWindow : Window
    {
        public EditWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void updateBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with c# but the reason is i guess the loop in the click function. It does what you said. Instead of loop you should only use the current listA element.

Answer (score 0):

In your button event handler, you are using a for loop to open an EditWindow for every entry in the list. Instead, only open one EditWindow and populate it with the specified entry.

Comment: I will play with the code some more. I might need to use a loaded event on the second window that pulls the list indexes from the main window when said button is clicked. The for loop was assigning the indexes correctly to the text box in the second window so that's why I left it in the example. But your right, the loop will trigger all of them. I guess the biggest issue is the assigning of the list indexes to show in the second windows text box on the button click. Button 2 triggers .show of second window and text box in second window reflects index 1 from list on main window. Thanks!